# Iphone dev app for companies

Tags: iphone

Lets say I have a client that wishes me to build a business app for the iphone. I would still need to enroll to the standard developer program so that the app can be installed on real devices and the only way for my client to install the app is through the app store? I cannot just distribute it to my client directly?

I'm just reading about how to start developing for iphone, so i'm a total noob. Any information is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a developer certificate to put an app on any iOS device with a stock OS.

What kind of certificate and how many you need depends on the type and amount of distribution you require, and the size of your client's company.

You most likely will need to join the iOS developer program ($99/annum) yourself to install and test your apps as you develop them.  In addition you can deploy Ad Hoc installations for up to 100 devices (including your own, your testers, your clients, plus, very importantly, including all repair replacements and upgrade devices).

Your client may not need any license if they only want a few copies and are willing to have you renew your Ad Hoc installs a few times per year.

If your client wishes to deploy an app in their own name outside their company or through the iTunes App store, then they need to apply to the iOS developer program themselves.

If your client is large enough to have a published Dunn & Bradstreet rating, and wishes to deploy only to their employees, then they can apply to the more expensive Enterprise iOS Developer program, and run their own internal app store.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you do need a developer license. No you can distribute it directly if you have each device setup on your account to do so. I am also pretty sure apple has a special license that makes it easier for handling enterprise applications you might want to send them an email to ask about it.

**EDIT**

Ok I found a link. It is more expensive the normal but this is definitely what you want for your company. It lets you do adhoc distribution across your company.

http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: Thanks, but I think the enterprise license only allows you to distribute your application without going through the app store to users of YOUR company. That's my understanding of it.

Comment: Yes, so maybe the thing to do would be to have your client company enroll in the enterprise program, to facilitate in-house distribution of apps.